# Pop function and linked list implementation

Tags: c++, linked-list, implementation

Alright guys, so I know how the pop function works obviously.  I also know that I need to set a LinkNode * top = head and that if top == NULL that you need to return NULL.  I'm just not sure what I'm honestly supposed to do after that.  The return is supposed to remove and return a value and the data type of the function is a pointer.

I'm not going to post my code on here unless people are honestly going to help me out because I've already been criticized greatly once and it was quite discouraging. :\

Comment: What language are you using? C++?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for helping me out ahead of time @Marlon

Comment: May I ask why you are doing manual linked list work in C++?  That would be straight C stuff.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan My guess is C++ data structures class.

Comment: @BleuCheese It's also better to post code. Granted some answerers could polish their social skills, but still they are usually thorough and mean well.

Comment: Besides, there is no stronger motivator for self-betterment than public humiliation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “I … know that I need to set a LinkNode * top = head and that if top == NULL that you need to
>   return NULL. I'm just not sure what I'm honestly supposed to do after that.”

Well, the things you mention have nothing to do with `pop`.

For a linked list, `pop` is about unlinking the first node. Depending on the level of abstraction the function might return (a pointer to) that node, or the node’s “value”, or nothing. At the lowest level of abstraction you want just the unlink functionality, which can go like this:

```
struct Node
{
    Node*     next;
    double    value;
};

Node* unlinked( Node*& p )
{
    Node* const    result = p;

    p = p->next;
    return result;
}
```

Then, as an example, a `pop` that destroys the node goes like this:

```
void pop( Node*& first )
{
    delete unlinked( first );
}
```

while a `pop` that returns the value in the node goes like this:

```
double pop( Node*& first )
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> p( unlinked( first ) );
    return p->value;
}
```

A subtle point here is whether the value is guaranteed to be copied before the node is destroyed. I'm just assuming it is. I leave it to the lawyers to find the standardese for that.

Cheers & hth.